# Remote PSQL and Case-Sensitivity

Tags: postgresql

I need run a query remotely to change an entry.

It looks like this:

```
PGPASSWORD=$secret psql -h $dbip -p $port -d $db -U $dbuser -c "UPDATE AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO set "URL" = 'https://testy.com' WHERE "URL" ='https://test.com';"
```

Now I know the company who crated the DB have set these tables as case-sensitive, so locally I can play with these tables using "", however, when pushing this remotely, I can't seem to get the case sensitivity working, I've tried some silly things to make it work like this:

```
PGPASSWORD=$secret psql -h $dbip -p $port -d $db -U $dbuser -c "UPDATE "AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO" set "URL" = 'https://testy.com' WHERE "URL" ='https://test.com';"

PGPASSWORD=$secret psql -h $dbip -p $port -d $db -U $dbuser -c "UPDATE '"AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO'" set "URL" = 'https://testy.com' WHERE "URL" ='https://test.com';"
```

None of which seem happy. So I'm hoping someone who knows can prevent me from ripping my hair out anymore.

Comment: You can fix the quotes, use a "here document" for the query or write it to a file and use `psql -f`.

Comment: Okay thank you for your quick response, sounds interesting, do i just swap -c with -f and add in the document path, then in the document which of the three commands I posted above would I place? I'm wondering how it would make a difference, because even when connected directly to the database I need to use quotes. It's not clear to me what I would put in the document that would make it work differently.

Comment: On the command-line you will need to escape the quotes. That is fiddly and none of your examples are right. A query in a file can be tested against a local copy of th database and then used unchanged against the remote one.

Comment: It's fine tested on a local copy, but this is in AWS RDS. So I can only send remote commands or be directly connected to the RDS console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping the quotes using `\` solved the issue:

```
"UPDATE \"TABLE\" set \"URL\" = 'https://newurl' WHERE \"URL\" = 'https://oldurl';"
```